# Loop code without manually pressing the button

Tags: button, neopixel

In a piece off code I am modifying I have a button connected to start the code and then it resets its self afterwards. Is they a way to make the arduino loop that code without manually pressing the button again?

This is a section off the code:

```c++
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif
#define PIN 6
#define BUTTON_PIN 9

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(120, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

bool oldState = HIGH;
int showType = 0;

void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0; //declare reset function @ address 0

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  // Get current button state.
  bool newState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

  // Check if state changed from high to low (button press).
  if (newState == LOW && oldState == HIGH) {
    // Short delay to debounce button.
    delay(20);
    // Check if button is still low after debounce.
    newState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
    if (newState == LOW) {
      showType++;
      if (showType > 9)
        showType=0;
      startShow(showType);
    }
  }

  // Set the last button state to the old state.
  oldState = newState;
}

void startShow(int i) {  
  colorWipe(strip.Color(75, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 75, 0), 50); // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 75), 50); // Blue
  theaterChase(strip.Color(75, 75, 75), 50); // White
  theaterChase(strip.Color(75, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 75), 50); // Blue
  rainbow(20);
  rainbowCycle(20);
  theaterChaseRainbow(50);
  resetFunc();  //call reset
}
```

Thanks Reece

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BULf5CfQ

Comment: Remove the `loop()` function, and rename `void startShow(int i)` as `void loop()`.

Comment: Move `startShow(showType);` to just above `  oldState = newState;`. That way it get called al the time, and the button still changes the showType.

Comment: Could you describe more clearly what you want to happen please? Do you want to wait for the button to be pressed then do the LED stuff forever?

Comment: Yeah that is correct I want to wait for the button press then for the led's loop forever.

Comment: If you want the led stuff to loop forever, why are you resetting the board at the end of that function?  Why not just let loop call it again?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Delta_G, there is no point in resetting your program.
What you should do is think your program in terms of the Arduino logic:

1. You put in `setup()` the code you want to run when your program
   starts.
2. You put in `loop()` the code you want to run over and over again.

In this case `loop()` is fairly simple, as the stuff you want to run
over and over again is the animation, thus:

```cpp
void loop() {
  colorWipe(strip.Color(75, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 75, 0), 50); // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 75), 50); // Blue
  theaterChase(strip.Color(75, 75, 75), 50); // White
  theaterChase(strip.Color(75, 0, 0), 50); // Red
  theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 75), 50); // Blue
  rainbow(20);
  rainbowCycle(20);
  theaterChaseRainbow(50);
}
```

Note that I removed the call to `resetFunc()`.

The stuff you want to do at startup is the initialization. Oh, wait. In
a comment you wrote “I want to wait for the button press”. So this also
has to be done before the program starts looping. Hence your `setup()`
should initialize stuff, *then* wait for the button press:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // Initialize the strip to all piwels off.
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();

  // Wait until the button is pressed.
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  while (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == HIGH)
      ; // do nothing
}
```